# Prove that $\sup\limits_n\min\left \{|x_n-y_n|,1 \right \}^2\le\sum\limits_n(x_n-y_n)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> Prove that $\bar{\rho}(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$, where:
>   $$d(x,y)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-y_n)^2\right)^{1/2}\qquad\bar{\rho}(x,y)=\sup_n\min\left \{|x_n-y_n|,1  \right \}$$

I am trying to prove that the $\ell^2$-topology contains the uniform topology.
To do so, it is sufficient to prove that one metric is less than or equal to the other.

I have done the following:

$\bar{\rho}(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$ if and only if $sup\left \{\bar{d}(x_{\alpha},y_{\alpha})/\alpha\in J  \right \}\leq (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-y_n)^2)^{1/2}$ if and only if $\bar{d}(x_{\alpha},y_{\alpha})<(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-y_n)^2)^{1/2}$ if and only if $min\left \{|x_{\alpha}-y_{\alpha}|,1  \right \}<(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-y_n)^2)^{1/2}$

but I do not know what else to do here.

Comment: Please use `\sup` and `\min`.

Comment: Not sure to see why showing this is a problem at all since, for every $k$, $$\min\{|x_k-y_k|,1\}^2\leqslant(x_k-y_k)^2\leqslant\sum_n(x_n-y_n)^2$$

Comment: @Did 
And if $\min\{|x_k-y_k|,1\}=1$ then why $1\leq(x_k-y_k)^2$? And if $x_k=y_k$?

Comment: ?? $\min(|a|,1)=1\iff|a|\geqslant1\implies a^2\geqslant1$. // If $x_k=y_k$ then $\min\{|x_k-y_k|,1\}\ne1$...

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if any $|x_{\alpha}-y_{\alpha}|\geq 1,$ then $\bar{\rho}(x,y)=1.$ Then in this case, $$\bar{\rho}(x,y)=1\leq ((x_{\alpha}-y_{\alpha})^{2}+C)^{1/2}=d(x,y),$$ where $C=\sum_{\alpha'\neq\alpha}(x_{\alpha'}-y_{\alpha'})^{2}\geq0.$ In the other case, $|x_{\alpha}-y_{\alpha}|<1$ for all $\alpha\in J,$ so $\bar{\rho}(x,y)=\sup\{|x_{\alpha}-y_{\alpha}|:\alpha\in J\}.$ Now by definition of $\sup,$ for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there is some $\alpha^{*}$ such that $|x_{\alpha^{*}}-y_{\alpha^{*}}|>\bar{\rho}(x,y)-\varepsilon,$ and if we let $|x-y|$ denote the sequence $(|x_{\alpha}-y_{\alpha}|)_{\alpha\in J},$ and $e_{\alpha}$ the sequence with zeros everywhere except for a $1$ in the $\alpha$ position, then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, since $\|e_{\alpha^{*}}\|=1$, $$\bar{\rho}(x,y)-\varepsilon<|\langle |x-y|,e_{\alpha^{*}}\rangle|\leq \||x-y|\|=d(x,y).$$ Since this is true for any $\varepsilon>0,$ we must have $\bar{\rho}(x,y)\leq d(x,y).$